# ng value not changing dynamically in input tag

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to build up a reservation booking system with payment using ASP.NET Core MVC and AngularJs. I am having difficulty changing a customer-form field value dynamically to use it as a variable later. The value (price) is not changing in the output value even though the view value changes dynamically.

My script is as follows:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.tourid = @ViewBag.TourID;

            $scope.count = 1;
            $scope.roomcost = 0;
            $scope.total = $scope.count * $scope.roomcost + $scope.count * @Decimal.Multiply((decimal)ViewBag.Kur, Model.Tour.TourCost);
            $scope.butondeposit = "btn-default";
            $scope.butonnormal = "btn-success";
            $scope.price = $scope.count * @Model.Tour.TourCost + $scope.count * $scope.roomcost;


            $scope.two = "btn-default";
            $scope.three = "btn-default";
            $scope.four = "btn-success";

            $scope.twoclick = function () {
                $scope.two = "btn-success";
                $scope.three = "btn-default";
                $scope.four = "btn-default";

                $scope.roomcost = 80;
                $scope.price = $scope.count * @Model.Tour.TourCost + $scope.count * $scope.roomcost;
                $scope.total = $scope.count * $scope.roomcost + $scope.count * @Decimal.Multiply((decimal)ViewBag.Kur, Model.Tour.TourCost);
            }

            $scope.threeclick = function () {
                $scope.two = "btn-default";
                $scope.three = "btn-success";
                $scope.four = "btn-default";

                $scope.roomcost = 60;

                $scope.price = $scope.count * @Model.Tour.TourCost + $scope.count * $scope.roomcost;
                $scope.total = $scope.count * $scope.roomcost + $scope.count * @Decimal.Multiply((decimal)ViewBag.Kur, Model.Tour.TourCost);

            }

            $scope.fourclick = function () {
                $scope.two = "btn-default";
                $scope.three = "btn-default";
                $scope.four = "btn-success";

                $scope.roomcost = 0.00;
                $scope.price = $scope.count * @Model.Tour.TourCost + $scope.count * $scope.roomcost;
                $scope.total = $scope.count * $scope.roomcost + $scope.count * @Decimal.Multiply((decimal)ViewBag.Kur, Model.Tour.TourCost);
            };

            $scope.increment = function () {
                $scope.count++;
                $scope.price = $scope.count * @Model.Tour.TourCost + $scope.count * $scope.roomcost;
                $scope.total = $scope.count * $scope.roomcost + $scope.count * @Decimal.Multiply((decimal)ViewBag.Kur, Model.Tour.TourCost);

            };

            $scope.decrement = function () {
                if ($scope.count == 1) {
                    return;
                }

                $scope.count--;
                $scope.price = $scope.count * @Model.Tour.TourCost + $scope.count * $scope.roomcost;
                $scope.total = $scope.count * $scope.roomcost + $scope.count * @Decimal.Multiply((decimal)ViewBag.Kur, Model.Tour.TourCost);
            };

        });
    </script>
}
```

cshtml part is as follows:

```
<div class="row" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8 col-xs-12">
        <aside>
            <div class="infoTitle">
                <h2>Satın Alma Detayları</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="bookDetailsInfo">
                <img src="~/img/TourTypes/@Model.Tour.Cities-.jpg" s alt="image">
                <div class="infoArea">
                    <h3>@Model.Tour.Cities Turu</h3>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>Tarihlerinde:  <span>@(Html.DisplayFor(t => Model.Tour.StartDate)) / @(Html.DisplayFor(t => Model.Tour.FinalDate)) </span></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Oda T&#252;r&#252;:
                            <button class="btn btn-outline {{two}}" ng-click="twoclick();">2 Ki&#351;ilik</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline {{three}}" ng-click="threeclick();">3 Ki&#351;ilik</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline {{four}}" ng-click="fourclick();">4 Ki&#351;ilik</button>
                                <li>
                                    <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>Guests:
                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="decrement();">–</button>
                                    {{count}}
                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="increment();">+</button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                <div class="priceTotal">
                    <h2>Total: <span> {{total}}</span></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>
```

The part where the problem occurs (where the variables should have changed dynamically) is this part:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Purchase.Price" ng-value="price">
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Purchase.Remaining" ng-value="price">
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Purchase.NumberofPerson" ng-value="count">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see these hidden input's inside `ng-app="myApp"` div.

To see the the effect in corresponding `hidden` input fields(binding), those input fields should be placed inside `ng-app` div, so that they will be considered as a part of angular application and binding will auto magically updated there.

Moving `hidden` fields inside `ng-app` div would solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot I resolved the issue! senin daşşana kurban

Comment: @NebihBaşaran didn't you add `name` attribute of your form fields?

Comment: I added the home attribute, but mistakenly in two different div parts. So I collected them all in one div

Comment: @NebihBaşaran I don't get you.

Comment: so I included ng-app="MyApp" in two different subdivisions.   But when you answered my question, I realized that the main div didn't have that property and put it in the main div after deleting the ones in two sub divs

Comment: @NebihBaşaran and that didn't worked, because you can't use to `ng-app` directive on page.

Comment: @NebihBaşaran I'm afraid. did my answer helped you?